# Cannot click() href element

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on "WANTED-LINK-!!!". Keep getting "element click intercepted" error!

HTML:

```
<span class="workable-tops">
  <a href="WANTED-LINK-!!!!" target="_blank"><span class="label-box" data-tops="names">Site555</span></a>
</span>
```

I am using selenium webdriver through python to accomplish this task.

```
dat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class="workable-tops"]')

dat.find_element_by_partial_link_text('WANT').click()
```

I would like a more efficient way of clicking the element and populating the associated page.

Comment: do you think we already know where is the `WANTED-LINK-!!` and its html structure? Do you think the post explain all aspects of the problem to reproduce it by the person who is completely unknown to the problem? Welcome to SO!! please read [mcve] and add necessary information to the post, thanks

Comment: Forgot to label html as code; it disappeared. I know you do not know the html. It's more of a typo, not an assumption of all-knowingness,

Comment: Re: the intercepted click, try waiting until the target element is "available": https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

Comment: Based on that markup, there is a span with a class of workable-tops but not an anchor element.  Try adjusting the selector.

Comment: The "Element click intercepted" error means another element on the page is positioned over top of the link. You will either need to wait for the element to become clickable, or find out which element is blocking the click. You might need to do something else on the page to unblock the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access it by tag via Beautifulsoup:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
    driver.get('link')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    my_text = soup.find_all("a", class_="workable-tops")
    print(my_text.text)
```

Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath to find the span by class name and the underlying a element shoul work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='workable-tops']/a").click()
```

If this doesn't work you may need to add a wait for the element to be clickable.

Comment: @Mixter    if it helped or any answer/question is/was helpful please accept/upvote  answer to help the readers in future

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and following xpath option.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='workable-tops']/a[./span[text()='Site555']]"))).click()
```

You need to imports followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Not working with xpath. I'm trying css:dat=wait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span[class="workable-tops"]'))).click().